# Adding permissions of Google Drive or Youtube Data API in Google Firebase Authentication?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can I add the permissions (scope) of other google services like drive, youtube etc in my google firebase authentication system?

I need this functionality in iOS (swift) and firebase is much easier to manage than using google client api. Please suggest.